# Unramified holomorphic map is isomorphism

Tags: riemann-surfaces

In my course about Riemann surfaces, the professor briefly mentioned the following as a fact that we shall just accept:

> If $X$ is a connected, compact Riemann surface and $f:X\to\mathbb C_\infty$ is a
> holomorphic unramified map, then $f$ is necessarily an isomorphism.

Which ingredients are used in order to prove this result? I'd like to have a go at a proof myself, but I'm not sure if I have the needed knowledge yet.

Comment: Your forgot to assume that $X$ is connected.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I added it, but I think this is generally part of the definition of a Riemann surface, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\mathbb{C}_{\infty} = \mathbb{C} \cup \{\infty\}$ is simply connected and $f$ is unramified (i.e. a covering map), [$f$ is a homeomorphism](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/755355/show-that-if-b-is-simply-connected-then-p-is-a-homeomorphism) and admits a continuous inverse $f^{-1}$. Then [the inverse is also holomorphic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1048204/the-inverse-of-a-bijective-holomorphic-function-is-also-holomorphic). The ingredients to understand the first answer would be some covering theory in topology, and I think the course you're taking may cover all the concepts you need to understand second answer.